# How can I get client ID and redirect URL when a user login to instagram through my site?

Tags: php, jquery, instagram

I need them to import their images into my site.

In their documentation they authenticate a use with a response code by the following url

> https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code

The above URL gives me only a code not all the images. And this is not my target. When a user come to my site and click on the Instagram login button with the user name and password then I need to import all the images of that user into my site.

Is that possible?

Comment: I hope you've already searched through [their api docs](http://instagram.com/developer/)?

Comment: @Blazemonger ..thx! but I don't find any clue there to solve this.. can you help me?

Comment: Did you check this page http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/ ?

Comment: yeah @MatRt but there not find such a clue.. what is in your mind?

Comment: Can you edit into the question the (relevant part of the) code you have already? That is always a good start, for this sort of thing.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand well. It seems that you have a full Console API will a lot of possibilities (retrieve the last photos of the user for example). Take a look at : http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/

Comment: Do you need any more help with this question? If an answer helped you solve your problem, please remember to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this until you got yourself an Access Token: http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Once you got that, you can call https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=YOURACCESSTOKEN

This will return you a JSON-Result of the newest Images of the User. Inside the pagination element, you will find a URL, that you can call to request the next Set of Images.

For more info on the parameters have a look at http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

A great way to get familiar with the API is to play around with the API console: http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/